# CheckBox in recyclerview not working and unable to pass the checked items to another fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

*I have a favorite checkbox in my recyclerview. My problem is checkbox is not clickable inside recyclerview. and i have to pass the ticked recyclerview items to another recyclerview. Really I got stucked here . anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.*

recycler_view_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="210dp">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@color/common_action_bar_splitter" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/PROJECT_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_avatar_size"
        android:layout_below="@id/divider"
        android:background="@drawable/mirlogo"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" STATUS "
        android:background="@color/common_action_bar_splitter"
        android:id="@+id/PROJECT_status"
        android:rotation="-45"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PROJECT_name"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Project"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PROJECT_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PROJECT_name"
            android:text="kerala"
            android:textColor="@color/common_action_bar_splitter"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PROJECT_type"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PROJECT_city"
            android:text="india"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/PROJECT_fav"
            android:layout_width="30sp"
            android:layout_height="30sp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/PROJECT_city"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:button="@null"
          />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

RecyclerviewAdapter

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.R;

public class HomeDataManager extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeDataManager.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView mProjectName, mProjectCity, mProjectType, mProjectStatus;
        ImageView mImage;
        CheckBox mCheck;


        RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mProjectName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_name);
            mProjectCity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_city);
            mProjectType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_type);
            mProjectStatus = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_status);
            mImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_image);
            mCheck = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PROJECT_fav);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        // get the single element from the main array

        final HomeProjects projects = HomeProjects.PROJECTS[i];
        // Set the values
        viewHolder.mProjectName.setText(projects.get(HomeProjects.Field.NAME));
        viewHolder.mProjectCity.setText(projects.get(HomeProjects.Field.CITY));
        viewHolder.mProjectType.setText(projects.get(HomeProjects.Field.TYPE));
        viewHolder.mProjectStatus.setText(projects.get(HomeProjects.Field.STATUS));
        viewHolder.mImage.setImageResource(projects.geti(HomeProjects.Field.IMAGE));
        viewHolder.mCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewHolder.mCheck.setChecked(!viewHolder.mCheck.isChecked());
                Log.d("Tag Name", "Log Message");

            }
        });

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return HomeProjects.PROJECTS.length;
    }
}
```

RecyclerviewFragment

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.HomeRecyclerDetailActivity;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.ProjectRecyclerDetailActivity;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.R;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.projectdatabase.HomeDataManager;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.projectdatabase.HomeProjects;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.projectdatabase.Projects;
import com.example.root5solutions.mirrealtors.projectdatabase.RecyclerClickListener;
import com.kogitune.activity_transition.ActivityTransitionLauncher;

public class RecyclerTab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_tab1_recycler, container, false);
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.home_recyclerview);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true); // to improve performance
        rv.setAdapter(new HomeDataManager()); // the projectdatabase manager is assigner to the RV
        rv.addOnItemTouchListener( // and the click is handled
                new RecyclerClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), HomeRecyclerDetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(HomeRecyclerDetailActivity.ID, HomeProjects.PROJECTS[position].getId());
                        ActivityTransitionLauncher.with(getActivity()).from(view).launch(intent);
                    }
                }));
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mike M : Sir . I have a custom shape for checked and non checked state . When i remove android:button="@null" , checkbox shows the default square box.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't notice the `background` attribute.  You wanna make that your `button` attribute instead. I.e., `android:button="@drawable/selector"`.

Comment: @RubinNellikunnathu i have same issue but not able to solve

Comment: i solved it by saving the checked arraylist in shared preference. then i get those values from my next fragment.

Comment: i am following this http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/recyclerview-with-checkbox-example.html, on button click i m getting selected value,but not able to store in pref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the onClickListener and set onCheckedChangeListener. Then save your list to an array in Sharedpreference

```
viewHolder.mCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(viewHolder.itemView, "Item Favorited", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar.show();
        } else {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(viewHolder.itemView, "Item Unfavorited", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar.show();
        }
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        mCheckedItems.put(position, isChecked);
        List<Integer> selected = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mCheckedItems.size(); i++) {
            final boolean checked = mCheckedItems.valueAt(i);
            if (checked) {
                selected.add(mCheckedItems.keyAt(i));
            }
        }
        Log.e("Checked Array = ", String.valueOf(selected));
        SharedPreferences prefs = v1.getContext().getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putString("Checkbox", String.valueOf(selected));
        edit.commit();
        Log.e("Shared Preference = ", String.valueOf(edit));
    }
});
```